# Create a network of unconnected, very small, full connected components

Tags: r, igraph, tidygraph

My final aim would be an undirected edgelist of this kind:

Per a network of 3 components, full connected, one with 1 node, one with 2 nodes, one with 3 nodes:

There would be 6 nodes, but since the first component is made only of 1 node, node1 has no edges.

```
tibble(from = c(2,4,4,5),
       to = (3,5,6,6)
)
```

But the number of components may higher then 3, let's say 30. The average number of edges within component would be ruled after `rpois(30,1)+1`.

In `tidygraph`, the function to create a complete graph would be `create_complete`, and in theory I could just keep generating complete graph and binding their edgelist. But in that case I would have a problem of naming the edges, and I could miss the unconnected nodes.

Answer (score 1):

## Update

If you want to show the cluster labels, you can use `membership` + `components` to add this attribute like below

```
set.seed(1)
do.call(
  graph.disjoint.union,
  lapply(
    rpois(30, 1) + 1,
    make_full_graph
  )
) %>%
  set_vertex_attr(name = "names", value = seq(vcount(.))) %>%
  set_vertex_attr(name = "cluster_label", value = membership(components(.))) %>% 
  as_tbl_graph(directed = FALSE)
```

which gives

```
# A tbl_graph: 62 nodes and 49 edges
#
# An undirected simple graph with 30 components
#
# Node Data: 62 x 2 (active)
  names cluster_label
  <int>         <dbl>
1     1             1
2     2             2
3     3             2
4     4             3
5     5             3
6     6             4
# ... with 56 more rows
#
# Edge Data: 49 x 2
   from    to
  <int> <int>
1     2     3
2     4     5
3     6     7
# ... with 46 more rows
```

---

You can use `disjoint.union` + `make_full_graph` like below (assuming you have 3 fully connected components with 1,2, and 3 nodes respectively)

```
library(tidygraph)
library(igraph)
do.call(
  graph.disjoint.union,
  lapply(
    1:3,
    make_full_graph
  )
) %>%
  set_vertex_attr(name = "names", value = seq(vcount(.))) %>% 
  as_tbl_graph(directed = FALSE)
```

which gives you

```
# A tbl_graph: 6 nodes and 4 edges
#
# An undirected simple graph with 3 components
#
# Node Data: 6 x 1 (active)
  names
  <int>
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5
6     6
#
# Edge Data: 4 x 2
   from    to
  <int> <int>
1     2     3
2     4     5
3     4     6
# ... with 1 more row
```

---

Regarding the use of `rpois(30,1)+1`, perhaps this could help if you replace `1:3` with `rpois(30,1)+1`, e.g.,

```
set.seed(1)
do.call(
  graph.disjoint.union,
  lapply(
    rpois(30,1)+1,
    make_full_graph
  )
) %>%
  set_vertex_attr(name = "names", value = seq(vcount(.))) %>% 
  as_tbl_graph(directed = FALSE)
```

and a graph is generated with the following info

```
# A tbl_graph: 62 nodes and 49 edges
#
# An undirected simple graph with 30 components
#
# Node Data: 62 x 1 (active)
  names
  <int>
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5
6     6
# ... with 56 more rows
#
# Edge Data: 49 x 2
   from    to
  <int> <int>
1     2     3
2     4     5
3     6     7
# ... with 46 more rows
```

Comment: This looks promising, but when I convert it into a `tidygraph`, it has no nodes. Which is not even this big issues, but it could mess with further operations if one want to integrate the `tbl_graph` with other data.

Also, not clear to me how to parameterise `rpois()` in this code.

Comment: @GiulioGCantone Pls see the update

Comment: Is there a way to assign a name to each component and to retrieve that name as an attribute of the node that is member of that component?

Comment: @GiulioGCantone See my update